# Day light Saving makes the calculation wrong

Tags: codenameone

Today in Us day Light Saving has been started which is PST from today.

I have Day length as 24 hours which makes the calculation wrong for today. I see issue in the following code which is used for day comparison.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick would be something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60000;    
Date temp = new Date(endDate1.getTime() + DAY);
c.setTime(temp);
int dh = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
if(dh != h) {
    // moving between daylight saving time
    if(dh > h) {
      // out of daylight saving
    } else {
      // into daylight saving
    }
}
```

Comment: changing the time on the simulator makes the SSL certificate to expire. How to test the App on simulator with future dates (Day light savings start and end dates) ? Please advise.

Comment: Use a longer terms SSL certificate or use test cases that avoid https requests